# How to handle external event in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I did the following ...

App\Providers\EventServiceProvider.php

in $listen

```
‘external.test_event’ => [ // EXTERNAL EVENT
           'App\Listeners\TestListener'
       ],
```

Then, In controller...

```
$eventData = [
      '12233e3',
      'Test-data'
                ];

event('external.test_event', $eventData);
```

Then inside the App\Listeners\TestListener.php, I did the following.

```
  public function handle($event)
    {
        $event->listen(....)
    }
```

It says, the listen method executed on string.